# getting facebook photos with graph api using fb->get() in php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

```
$photos=$fb->get("/me/albums?fields=picture",$accessToken)->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
    foreach ($photos as $key => $value) 
    {
    echo $value['data'];
    }
```

I want to fetch photos from facebook but getGraphEdge() return null array..help

Comment: Does your app have permission to access the user’s photos?

Comment: Yes i have check marked for permission

Answer (score 0):

Use `getGraphNode()` instead for images and photos. You also need to get permissions first. For more info, you can go to their [official documetation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/)

Comment: i have checked permission and i am gettting output in graph explorer see the image

Comment: Then use `getGraphNode()` instead of `getGraphEdge()`

Comment: getGraphEdge() returns

Comment: {
   "data": [
      
   ]
}

Comment: Do you have any example you have performed ?

Comment: This is what is say.. Use `getGraphNode()`

Comment: Try this `$photos=$fb->get("/me/albums?fields=picture",$accessToken)->getGraphNode()`

Comment: and then `print_r($photos)`

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException' with message 'Unable to convert response from Graph to a GraphNode because the response looks like a GraphEdge. Try using GraphNodeFactory::makeGraphEdge() instead.' in C:\wamp\www\rtCamp\Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNodeFactory.php on line 224

Comment: Hmm, I have read their documentation. it was writted graphNode for this purpose

Comment: Try this just `$photos=$fb->get("/me/albums?fields=picture",$accessToken)->getGraphEdge()`

Comment: Ok i got output by using getGraphEdge() and by printing it with print_r

Comment: and `print_r($photos)`

Comment: Was there problem in foreach loop?

Comment: but output is displaying that Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphEdge Object ( [request:protected] => Facebook\FacebookRequest Object ( [app:protected] => Facebook\FacebookApp Object ( [id:protected] => 221982878480421 [secret:protected] => c8e24b5e89b1e0901574897190ff5e72 ) [accessToken:protected] =>

Comment: Thats not the proper output I think

Comment: What is the key images in json array in explorer?

Comment: Yes. I think url is your image. Try fetching it

Comment: says undefind index